# Git Workflow involving cherry picking changes from master to release

Tags: git, branch

Our team has the following workflow. Two branches:

- master: where all the changes are committed and reviewed;
- release: this is always what's in production (push on this one triggers a deployment)

Developers make changes on master, changes are reviewed and tested, from time to time *one change* (which is not necessarily the latest one, or the only one on master) gets approval, and gets cherry picked to release for deployment.

The problem with this is that we are cherry picking individual changes from master to release after having validated them in master. This means that we are testing changes in one context, validating them and then expecting them to work just as well in another context.

Does this workflow/problem have a name? How would you go about fixing this?

Comment: One thing you should know about cherry picking is that it changes your commit SHA1 id i.e. the id on your master and release branch will be different for the same commit. It's like two different histories for both branches. Are considering this fact for the workflow? Are you not facing issues when a feature consist of multiple commits?

Comment: production issues would become difficult to resolve and merge back.I don't think this is a good way to go about it.I think you should decide before in hand which changes should be going to release and merge accordingly to another branch where the changes get tested.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the context of both branches is concerned, if both branches commits are in sync and the testing environment is similar to production then there is very less chance of deployment issues coming up.

But, I feel the process of cherry picking on a public shared branch is not a good approach.

1. Cherry picking will change your commit id i.e. same changes in two different branch will have two different commit ids. This will impact searching of any particular commits in future as there will be no link to when the changes were done and when was it released.
2. Reverting any changes will be a pain. Since there will be two commit id for same changes, you will have to first find the commit id in master and find the other commit id in release and revert both.

A better approach would be to follow merging strategy i.e. you make changes to master branch and merge to release branch. In this strategy, an additional merge commit will be added and your release branch but your feature commit will be having the same id as it was in master.

1. This will give a history of commits done and commits merged, also helping in backtracking to a particular commit. You can relate as to when the commits were done and when was it released.
2. Reverting will be as simple as reverting the merge commit.

An example of using this approach would be [GitFlow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html).